# VTerm: Program characters seem to show in incorrect width/font

Tags: fonts

In VTerm, some of the display characters of [a fairly graphical program called `btop`](https://github.com/aristocratos/btop) seems to not be displayed in the right width (or perhaps not in the right font? I can't tell).

[image: btop in VTerm]

In comparison, here is what it looks like in Ubuntu's terminal:

[image: btop in Ubuntu terminal]

I've set Emacs' font to `Ubuntu Mono`, which is the same one as the terminal. I know that has worked, since clicking anywhere in VTerm and then hitting `M-x describe-font RET` returns this:

```
name (opened by): -DAMA-Ubuntu Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-25-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1
       full name: Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=25:foundry=DAMA:weight=normal:slant=normal:width=normal:spacing=100:scalable=true
       file name: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/UbuntuMono-R.ttf
            size: 25
          height: 26
 baseline-offset:  0
relative-compose:  0
  default-ascent:  0
          ascent: 21
         descent:  5
   average-width: 13
     space-width: 13
       max-width: 13
```

I'd like to find out more by myself, but I'm just not quite sure where to go from here. It kinda seems that the fancy UTF-8 characters like `⣀` and `╭ ─ ┐` take more width than they are supposed to.

I've found [this issue](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm/issues/563) on VTerm's GitHub repo, however that issue doesn't suggest any solution ("It's an Emacs problem"), nor does it even say whether there is a solution.

The 'bad' screenshots of that issue look better than mine; there doesn't seem to be a gap between each of the characters. Not sure how to remove that gap in my config either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put point on one of the characters from the progress bar, and use `describe-char` to double check what font they are in. (They appear to be causing the largest misalignment.) You may actually need to copy some text out of the vterm buffer and paste it into another to do this properly.

There are a couple of possibilities depending on the results you get:

The first is that the progress bar is created from glyphs taken from the Ubuntu Mono font, but that your other terminal (you didn’t mention which one) does not. Some terminals choose to draw this type of graphical character directly, ignoring the glyphs from the font. This is often done to ensure that they are always exactly the right size. libvterm does not appear to have this capability.

The second possibility is that Ubuntu Mono does not contain glyphs for these characters. When that happens, the application must fall back to other similar fonts to find a glyph to draw. If that fallback font is chosen poorly, then the alignment will be wrong. Worse, there is no standard way to choose a fallback; Emacs and your other terminal could be doing it differently.

The third possibility is that your other terminal clips all characters to the size of the character grid if they are too large. This would make the problem much less apparent. Emacs, however, does not do this.

In my own case, only the braille is causing misalignment. Emacs is falling back from my normal font, Input Mono Condensed, to some other font, Free Symbola Semicondensed. The metrics don’t perfectly match, so the braille characters are a slightly different width than everything else.

Comment: Turns out my case is the second one you described. Characters like the box corners are drawn with other fonts such as `Nimbus Roman` or `FreeSans`, and I suppose the `Ubuntu Mono` font doesn't have these characters. Guess the other terminal was trimming the characters, or something similar like what you said. I'll just have to find a font with which the program's output is readable enough.

BTW I did mention the terminal (albeit not super explicitly): it's Ubuntu's default terminal (CTRL-ALT-T).

Comment: Searched this a bit further. Like you, I found a font (`Nimbus Mono PS`) that supports all `btop` characters except the braille. Thankfully, `btop` has an option (if you hit `o`) that allows changing the "Graph symbols". I changed them to `tty` so that it wouldn't use braille characters to draw the graphs, got out of it using `q`, and now `btop` looks almost perfect (except that there's a gap between lines; not a huge deal): https://i.imgur.com/NKiVzFw.png